# Hide the app from screen but not from taskbar

Tags: python, pyqt5, taskbar

I would like to hide the app from screen but not from taskbar, I tried this:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.show()
w.resize(0, 0)
```

but it doesn't work, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **QMainWindow** instead of **QWidget**, then I override the **focusInEvent** and **focusOutEvent** events.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from sys import argv, exit

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        print('focusInEvent')
        self.setWindowTitle('focusInEvent')
        self.showMinimized()

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        print('focusOutEvent')
        self.setWindowTitle('focusOutEvent')
#        self.showMinimized()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.showMinimized()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is the point of using a window if you never show it? Why not just use a [system tray icon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html)?

Comment: ekhumoro I used it but I don't write the code for simplifying the code

Answer (score 1):

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.showMinimized()
```

Comment: If I push `ALT + TAB` I can see the app with window, there is some event to catch and put the `w.showMinimized()` too?