# PyQt5: Event when my app is focused

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I would like to execute "onFocus" function when the app is focused, due to when I navigate from apps with **ALT+TAB** it shows the window, the code:

```
def onFocus(w):
    w.showMinimized()
    # another stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    onFocus(w)
    exit(app.exec_())
```

What is the event for do this? Thank you very much

Comment: SOLVED HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544941/hide-the-app-from-screen-but-not-from-taskbar